# Jquery mouseover .css not working for font size

Tags: jquery

Hi all I have this script, and I want when `.mouseover` width < 300px font-size make 16px but not work, how can I do this?

```
$('.mouseover').mouseover(function(){
  var a = $(this).width();
  if( a < 300 ){
  $('.video_name').css({"font-size":"16px"});
});
```

Comment: I can’t see anything obviously wrong with your JS. Got an example of your HTML?

Comment: there is a missing `)` at the end of the script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/982oe17q/2/

```
$('.mouseover').mouseover(function(){
    var a = $(this).width();
    if (a < 300) {
        $('.video_name').css({"font-size":"16px"});
    }
});
```

You were missing the closing `}` for the anonymous function, closing `)` for the mouseover function, and a `;` at the end of the mouseover call.